# Jenkins SecretFile Decrypt

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd, jenkins-cli

Normally, I can decrypt a password or a  secret-text like below

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
def jenkinsCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
Jenkins.instance,
null,
null
);
for (creds in jenkinsCredentials) {
if(creds.id == 'XYZ'){ 
for password-------> println(creds.password)  
-----OR------  
for secret-text-----> println(creds.secret) 
                           }
}
```

But I could not find a way to decrypt a secret-file with this method. When I need to get the last version of the replaced file this becomes a problem. How can I get the uploaded or the replaced last version secret file that is registered in Jenkins credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the working function format for the secretFile

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
def jenkinsCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
Jenkins.instance,
null,
null
);
for (creds in jenkinsCredentials) {
if(creds.id == 'XYZ'){ 
println(IOUtils.toString(creds.getContent(), "UTF-8"))  
                     }
}
```

So, the new println line works after the fuction add

Comment: you don't have to use apache commons, there is a simpler groovy method for this, Check the answer.

Comment: when I replace "println(creds.secret)" with "creds.getContent().getText()" it does not give error but returns empty in my jenkins/script window, maybe I miss a point and need to add some extra lines.

Comment: You can even pass the charset  if that's needed `getText("UTF-8")`. Not sure what the issue is, but it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the decrypted content of the file. You can read the content with [getContent()](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/plain-credentials/org/jenkinsci/plugins/plaincredentials/impl/FileCredentialsImpl.html#getContent()) which return a [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true) and then use [getText()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#getText()) to convert it into a `String`.

```
creds.getContent().getText()
```